# Change font Cyrillic

Tags: fonts

I want to change the font of the highlighted text(which is also bold, underlined and italic). Looking for compatible new font which more thicker and 'stronger' to focus the eye on it.
[image]

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage[
 left=15mm,
 top=21mm,
 right=15mm,
 bottom=24mm,
 headsep=12.5mm,
 headheight=14.5pt, %%% 3mm is too small
 heightrounded
]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp} % for the arrow
\usepackage{longdivision}
\input longdiv.tex

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\linespread{1.1}



\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\begin{center}
    \underline{\textbf{\textit{Урок 1}}}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \underline{\textbf{\textit{Урок 2}}}
\end{center}
\underline{\textbf{\textit{Стр.3, Зад.1}}} \textrightarrow Тестов тескт 1; 
\\
\\
\underline{\textbf{\textit{Стр.3, Зад.2}}} \textrightarrow 
Тестов текст 2;
\\
\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Boldface italic underlined is already a hard punch in the eye of the reader. Boldface *or* italic is sufficient to express emphasis, triple emphasis is too much. Never use underlining for emphasis, by the way: it used to be the only available device with typewriters, but you're not using a typewriter.

Comment: You use Times New Roman. So you can download the `.ttf` file of [Times New Roman Extra Bold](https://www.google.com.vn/search?hl=en&source=hp&ei=P_bvW7ntI9LN-QbKgpyYAw&q=times+new+roman+extra+bold&btnK=Google+Search&oq=times&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.35i39l2j0i131i67j0i67l5j0i203j0i67.791.1387..2361...0.0..0.117.665.0j6......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i131.YCHVZGmpecA) and use it as a local font family in your document.